# How is DOM build after object has changed?

Tags: angular

I have some array of lets say orders. In current architecture, I am getting the list of all users every 5 seconds (I know that this is not the best approach, but unfortunately that wasn't my choice). Now, as my array grows (around 1000), and I want to display some image for each order, I can see a blink in the table (since I use `Object.assign(this.orders, success.json()`).

Due to this annoying blink, which I guess comes from the fact that angular2 needs to rebuild the front end each time I fetch new data, I am wondering how angular2 rebuilds the HTML components after the object has changed? Is there anything else that I can do so that angular doesn't rebuild the whole structure, only the parts that are missing?

Comment: Please add some code that demonstrates what you are doing. You can find how Angular does it in https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/f39c9c9e75671a7e235734b6b8aef263f6dff254/modules/%40angular/common/src/directives/ng_for.ts#L72

Comment: Use track by: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36322829/how-to-use-track-by-inside-ngfor-angular-2. This prevents angular from rebuilding the while dom.

Comment: @JBNizet, have you ever used ith with NgforOf?

Comment: Not that I remember. I haven't use Angular2 much yet. Why are you asking the question?

Comment: You could loop through the orders from the response yourself and only add the new items.