# How is Angular's *ngFor loop implemented?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I wonder how does Angular's `*ngFor` directive actually work under the hood? I would like to know the whole process that happens when I use the directive.

**For downvoters**: I've seen the [ng-for-of](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/directives/ng_for_of.ts) file, although there is no single usage of passed to `*ngFor` array's e.g. `join()` method that I know is invoked. Thanks for your support :)
Here is the plunker that shows the behavior: https://plnkr.co/edit/IXVxWrSOhLBgvSal6PWL?p=preview

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/directives/ng_for_of.ts

Comment: See also https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#inside-ngfor, which explains it in the context of the template syntax.

Comment: @echonax, @jonrsharpe, thanks guys, although it doesn't explain why e..g `join()` method is invoked on array passed to `*ngFor`. Please take a look at included plnkr, thanks!

Comment: Check this example https://jsfiddle.net/x1jyfuck/. There is nothing to do with angular. You should be careful when write such code

Comment: Hey @yurzui, this is very interesting! Could you explain why join() is looped in your example?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Here is a high level overview. Suppose you define your template like this:

```
<span *ngFor="let item of items">{{item}}</span>
```

Then it's transformed to the following by the compiler:

```
<ng-template let-item [ngForOf]="items">
    <span>{{item}}</span>
</ng-template>
```

Then Angular applies `ngForOf` directive to the template element. Since this directive's host element is template, it injects the `templateRef`. It also injects the `viewContainerRef` that acts as an anchor element and will be used to add DOM elements alongside:

```
  constructor(
       private _viewContainer: ViewContainerRef, 
       private _template: TemplateRef<NgForOfContext<T>>,
```

The directive defines `ngForOf` as an input and then waits until it's initialized and creates a differ:

```
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
      const value = changes['ngForOf'].currentValue;
          this._differ = this._differs.find(value).create(this.ngForTrackBy);
```

Then on each check detection cycle it compares the values to the previous values using this differ:

```
  ngDoCheck(): void {
    if (this._differ) {
      const changes = this._differ.diff(this.ngForOf);
      if (changes) this._applyChanges(changes);
    }
  }
```

If the values changed, it applies the changes doing the the following things:

1) generates embedded view context for each item in `items`

```
context = new NgForOfContext<T>(null !, this.ngForOf, -1, -1)
```

2) creates embedded view with this context using the `templateRef` which effectively renders new value in the DOM

```
this._viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(
                this._template, context , currentIndex);
```

3) adds relevant values to context

```
  viewRef.context.index = i;
  viewRef.context.count = ilen;
  viewRef.context.$implicit = record.item;`
```

Now, your question:

> although it doesn't explain why e..g join() method is invoked on array
>   passed to

It's called by the function `normalizeDebugBindingValue` [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/61e66184297d02652dd554d454173d7dbdbca2eb/packages/core/src/view/services.ts#L420) because your application is running in the development mode:

```
function normalizeDebugBindingValue(value: any): string {
  try {
    // Limit the size of the value as otherwise the DOM just gets polluted.
    return value != null ? value.toString().slice(0, 30) : value;
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  } catch (e) {
    return '[ERROR] Exception while trying to serialize the value';
  }
}
```

If you enable production mode, this function will no longer be called. Check [the plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/U9iudo1DpSI3EoKicZuN?p=preview).

Comment: I also want to print `{{ array }}` in template. Production mode won't help me)

Comment: bad luck I guess...)

Comment: Your explanation of `ngFor` is great :)

Comment: @yurzui, glad you liked after all )

Comment: Thank you very much for your extensive answer and explanation of why the `join()` method is invoked, Maximus!

Comment: @DanielKucal, you're welcome, it's pity the question got downvoted. It's pretty broad I guess

Comment: Yeah, I should have prepared this question better. I honestly didn't expect it to get so much attention, as my last 2 questions haven't got any answers. Thanks again

Comment: @MaxKoretskyiakaWizard Is there any difference if you return some unique ID from trackByFn and some constant which would be the same for all elements in the array (e.g. `trackByFn = () => true;`)? It seems to have the same behaviour in both cases.