# Angular - How to not rebuild a list created with *ngFor any time an event on each element of the list is fired

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

I have a simple list of `<div>` generated using `*ngFor` directive, something like

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items() | async ; let i=index" 
  [ngClass]="getItemClass(i)"
  (click)="itemClick(i)"</div>
```

As you see, the list is filled asynchronously any time the Observable returned by the method `items()` emits. In my case such Observable is a `ReplaySubject`, if this can be of any use to know. I then define the classes to be applied to each `<div>` element using the method `getItemClass`.

I want also to react to a click event on each item using the method `itemClick(i: number)`.

**Problem**

Any time a `div` element is clicked, i.e. any time the `itemClick(i: number)` method is run, it seems that the entire list of `<div>`s is rebuilt. I come to this conclusion observing that any time a `div` element is clicked, also the `items()` method is run.

**Question**

Is it possible to avoid rebuilding the list when one of the `<div>` elements is clicked? I have already set `changeDetection` to be ***OnPush*** but it does not seem to solve my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular change detection process repaint the dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45311502/angular-change-detection-process-repaint-the-dom)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, even with onPush the change detection will be triggered. And that will cause the evaluation of the index() method. This is sort of lost in the documentation. Any event that will bubble to the zone.js code, will trigger a change detection on every component from the root to that component. Setting onPush will not prevent that. In order to avoid recreating the components in the loop you need to add trackBy.

In your html template:

```
<li *ngFor="let hr of heroes;trackBy: trackByFn">{{hr.name}}</li>
```

and then in the component you have to define the function:

```
trackByFn(index, item) {    
   return item.id  
}
```

Item is passed from the loop. and if the id of that item will not change the item will not be recreated.

Also I would get rid of the index() method and replace it with the variable. As I mentioned it will be evaluated every time the change detection runs. I wrote an article about some performance tricks that you can do to speed up your application.

https://medium.com/12-developer-labors/some-things-i-wish-i-knew-before-i-start-to-work-with-angular-part-2-performance-47cd834dc409

Comment: Thanks, it make perfect sense. Do you know whether you can get the same result using NgZone?

Comment: There is but it is not worth it. It basically boils down to disabling NgZone in angular and then triggering change detection manually. It is hard as there is a lot of corner cases to consider. Pretty cool article on the subject: https://blog.angularindepth.com/do-you-still-think-that-ngzone-zone-js-is-required-for-change-detection-in-angular-16f7a575afef