# How does the implementation of a scoped variable work in *ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, scope, angular2-directives, angular-directive

In Angular we can use ***ngFor** in the following way:

```
<li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
  {{ hero }}
</li>
```

But how does Angular define the scoped variable **hero**
and would I be able to implement the same thing?
I am only interested in the scoped variable and not in the looping part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I was able to solve my problem. I failed to realize that I can use the following syntax myself:

```
*ngFor="let test...."
```

With this I was able to create the following directive:

```
import { Directive, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appWrapper]',
})
export class WrapperDirective {
  constructor(viewContainer: ViewContainerRef, template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(
      template,
      { ['$implicit']: 'Max Mustermann' },
      0,
    );
  }
}
```

This directive can now be used like this:

```
<div *appWrapper="let name">{{ name }}</div>
```

Is there a way to get rid of the **let name** part?

[This Stackoverflow post helped me to implement my idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44970386/how-is-angulars-ngfor-loop-implemented)

Answer (score 0):

All the public variables (functions) defined in component.ts are accesible from the component.html and can be showed using [interpolation and template expresion](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#interpolation-and-template-expressions)

When you has a *ngFor, when you define "let variable of array", variable is accesible **inside** the *ngFor and is each element of the array

If you want to declare a variable use [ng-if-let](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#storing-conditional-result-in-a-variable), e.g.

```
<div *ngIf="'hello word' as greeting">
  {{greeting}}
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I think you got my question wrong.
Take a look at my solution, this way you can understand my question.

Comment: sorry my answer, I update it. Is ng-if-let you are looking for?

Comment: I was just looking for a way to pass a scoped variable from a "component" (directive in this case) to its child