# How Angular Directives Work? (ng*For) as an Example

Tags: javascript, angular, dom

I want to know how Angular Directives work behind the scene, are these Directives use DOM web api or what?

Comment: Try reading through **[Angular's Structural Directigves Guide](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives)**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44970386/how-is-angulars-ngfor-loop-implemented - this has a good explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular is based on Typescript/JavaScript. You do not necessarily need the browser's Web-API for directives like `*ngFor` or `*ngIf`. For others it may be the case. I'd say it is a combination of both.