# *ngFor angular click display content calling a function

Tags: angular, typescript, accordion, ngfor

I have a content in a *ngFor loop. When I click on the content, like an accordion, I call a function passing the id of that object that returns the detail of the object. The problem is that now, when I click, It changes for each accordion and not separately. the html is

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let data of datas" (click)="fetchData(data.dataId); data.expanded = !data.expanded" style="cursor:pointer; width: 100%;">
    <div class="card-body" style="display:flex">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{data.name}} </h5>
    </div>
    <ng-container *ngIf="data.expanded">
        {{dataContent.descriptionDetail}}
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

and in my component

```
fetchData(dataId:number) {
        this.service.fetchData(dataId).subscribe(
            (result) => {
                this.dataContent = result;
                console.log(result);
            }
        );
    }
```

If I click in the first accordion, i get the correct dataContent. But if I click the second one, it gets me the second dataContent value correctly but also in the first accordion. Thanks

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I can't create an example for this issue because i don't know where fetch the data. But what I need, and I can't do, is get the details for each accordion when is expanded. The detail is different for each accordion and I can open all of them and each with their detail. Now, if i open one of more of them, I can only show the detail of the last of in each accordion.

Comment: You can mock the data..

Comment: Have you tried using a (TrackBy)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42108217/how-to-use-trackby-with-ngfor]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `this.dataContent` is a single variable which is being displayed in every `ng-container`. What you need to do instead is somehow manage a collection of `data` objects and their respective `dataContent`.

One approach would be to maintain a collection of objects in, say, a [Map](https://howtodoinjava.com/typescript/maps/) like this:

```ts
// In your component class
dataContents: Map<any, any> = new Map<any, any>();

fetchData(dataId: number) {
    this.service.fetchData(dataId).subscribe(result => {
        this.dataContents.set(dataId, result);
    });
}
```

And then in your markup:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="data.expanded">
    {{dataContents.get(data.id)}}
</ng-container>
```

See an example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pw3mp2) (StackBlitz)

With this approach, you can also avoid fetching the data from the server each time, if you want to. In `fetchData` you would just wrap the `this.service.fetchData` call in `if (!this.dataContents.has(dataId) || !this.dataContents.get(dataId))`.