# ngFor is updated automatically

Tags: angular

I have a list in `list-components` as like as given below:

**list.components.ts**

```
import { BsModalService, BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { EditModalComponent } from "...../edit-modal.component";

@Component({
   selector: 'list',
   templateUrl: './list.component.html',
   providers: [ Service ]
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
    bsModalRef: BsModalRef;
    list:[];

    constructor(private modalService: BsModalService, private service: Service) {  }

    ngOnInit() { this.service.getList().subscribe(data => this.list = [...data ] )  }

    edit({ thisData }) {
       const initialState = { data: thisData };
       this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(EditModalComponent, { initialState });
       this.bsModalRef.content.updateSingleValue = (id, name, value) => this.service.update(id, { [name]: value })
    }
}
```

**list.components.html**

```
<table-list [(data)]="list" (action)="edit($event)"></table-list>
```

Now calling `table-list` component as like as given below:

**table-list.components.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: "table-list",
  inputs: ["data"],
  templateUrl: "./table-list.components.html"
})
export class TableListComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    @Input() data: any[];
    @Output() editAction = new EventEmitter();

    handleEdit($root) {
       this.editAction.emit({ thisData: $root });
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
       // this will execute in every form data update
    }
}
```

**table-list.components.html**

```
<table>
   <tr *ngFor="let $root of data">
      <td> {{ $root.name }} </td>
      <td> {{ $root.email}} </td>
      <td> <button (click)="handleEdit()">edit</button> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here as you can see, just displaying list of data and a **edit** button. when user click on **edit** button, it will call `edit({ thisData })` method of `list.component.ts`. Then `edit({ thisData })` method will open a `modal` with `input form`. So when user edit any form data, it will execute the following code and update single data. And it works properly.

`this.bsModalRef.content.updateSingleValue = (id, name, value) => this.service.update(id, { [name]: value })`

My problem is, when user update any **form data**, it will also update all `list-data` (**list** is re-generated). I just want to update **single data** from **list** (don't want to re-generate **list**). I put some debugger and found out that when any form data is updated, it trigger `ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges)` of **table-list.component.ts** and re-generated the **list**.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use `trackBy` in your `*ngFor` loop. This way only items that have changed will rerender. See top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42108217/how-to-use-trackby-with-ngfor)

Comment: No result, still same