# Angular ngFor loop trackBy Function

Tags: angular

I am trying to understand `trackBy` in angular `ngFor` but I am not able to find any difference whether I use it or not.
Below is my code

**.ts**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  users = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Test User 1', role: 'ADMIN'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Test User 2', role: 'DEV'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Test User 3', role: 'DEV'},
  ]

  add(){
    const id = this.users.length+1
    let user = {
      id: id,
      name : `Test User ${id}`,
      role: 'Dev'
    }
    // this.users.push(user)
    this.users = [...this.users , user]
  }

  delete(i){
    this.users.splice(i,1)
  }

  fnc(index, user){
      return index
  }
}
```

**.html**

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Role</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let user of users;let i = index;trackBy:fnc">
            <td>{{user.id}}</td>
            <td>{{user.name}}</td>
            <td>{{user.role}}</td>
            <td>
                <button (click)="add()">Add</button>
                <button (click)="delete(i)">Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Working link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3gnjr2

I am checking in developer tools inside the inspect tab. If I use trackBy or not whenever I add an Item or delete icon nodes are being rendered in same way

Comment: this demonstration might help, https://medium.com/@jinalshah999/trackby-with-ngfor-directives-in-angular-application-bd4d0db288eb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TrackBy is mainly used to get better performance.

It is not a 100% clear from your question what you expect to happen, but the trackBy function will not have any effect on what the final DOM looks like. If you are using trackBy, it will make sure that DOM elements that have not changed will not be destroyed and rebuilt. No point in rerendering DOM elements that is based on data that haven't changes.

Comment: yes that is my confusion I am trying to see the effect and in both cases, whether I use traceBy or not already rendered items not being destroyed

Answer (score 2):

`trackBy` used to optimize performance of rendering after array update. With `trackBy` Angular understands which nodes it can reuse, which should be deleted/created.
Also: track by which returns index is useless (trackBy should return uniq id of your array item).

There is good article about `trackBy`: https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5

Comment: thanks for answering I already gone through this article and trying to do the same. in both the cases, I can see that already added items not destroyed whether I use traceBy or not.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add something.
You can view the difference by looking into Elements tab of Developer tools.

For Ex: In Chrome

Right Click on your list => Select *Inspect* => View as values of list are rendered

When your list items are changed, only changed list item will be updated if you use unique id in **trackBy** function, which effectively increases the rendering of list which is updated frequently.  **If this unique Id matches the previous one, then Angular will not detect the change and particular list item will not be re-rendered**. Even when change detection is called frequently, list rendering process is optimized by using trackBy.

Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42108217/how-to-use-trackby-with-ngfor) for more information.