# ngx-bootstrap Accordion closing when subscribing to API method

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap-accordion

I have an ngx-bootstrap accordion that closes the open panel each time I call data back from an API using a `.subscribe()` method. The content in the headers of the Accordion all change seamlessly with no apparent reload, but as the change of the content inside the accordion is controlled with a range slider it's very annoying to have to re-open the panel each time the rage slider is changed.

Is there anyway I can stop this from happening?

HTML:

```
<accordion [isAnimated]="true" [closeOthers]="true">
    <accordion-group *ngFor="let r of reccs; let i = index" panelClass="customClass">
        <div class="row text-left" accordion-heading>
            <div class="col">
                <h4><strong [ngStyle]="{'color': brand?.colours.primary}">{{ r.name }}</strong> <small [ngStyle]="{'color': brand?.colours.secondary}"> {{ r.financials.representativeAmountAsString }} {{termTimeDisplay}}</small> <span *ngIf="i===0" class="badge badge-success ml-3">Recommended</span></h4>
                <p [ngStyle]="{'color': brand?.colours.tertiary}">{{ r.tagline }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div id="progress" class="container">
                    <div class="hex-container">
                        <div *ngFor="let p of r.products" [popover]="popTemplate" [popoverTitle]="p.type" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave" [ngClass]="{'product-included': p.inclusivity === 'included', 'product-not-required' : p.inclusivity === 'notRelevant'}">
                            <ng-template #popTemplate>{{p.name}}</ng-template>
                            <img src="../../assets/questions/progress/1.png" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row mt-3">
                <div class="col">
                  <p>{{ r.name }}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </accordion-group>
          </accordion>
```

API Method Call:

```
loadRecommendations(term: number, paymentCycle: string) {
    // Get the choices from the API
    this.reccommendationsService.getRecommendations(term, paymentCycle).subscribe(res => {
      // Load the choices to angular
      this.choices = res;
      // Initalise the reccommendations array
      this.reccs = new Array();
      // Load the array with choices
      for (const c of this.choices.choices) {
        // Make a stringly typed choice model
        this.recc = c;
        // Add choice model to the array
        this.reccs.push(this.recc);
      }
      this.reccs.reverse();
      if (this.reccs) {
        this.chiocesPresent = true;
        this.bestProduct = this.reccs[0];
      } else {
        this.chiocesPresent = false;
      }
      this.allInclusive();
      this.allInclusiveFeatures();
    });
  }
```

Slider:

```
<div class="text-center sliders">
        <input type="range" min="6" max="60" step="6" class="slider" [(ngModel)]="term" id="term" (change)="loadRecommendations(this.term, this.termTime)">
        <p class="text-right mt-2">{{term}} months</p>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a common problem when working with Angular.
Your content is updated so Angular has no choice but to destroy it from the dom, and create it again, losing track of the item..
Hopefully, solutions exist !

I would advice you to use `trackByFn`
https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5

This answer also explains really well what it does and how to use it https://stackoverflow.com/a/45391247/10265078