# Angular 2: Change Detection of array inside the object

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object, nested-object

I have an object as follows which comes through @Input.

```
@Input() data;
//**
{
  "class_a":["John","Harr y"],
  "class_b":["Joseph","Phlip","David"],
  "class_c":[]
}  
**//
```

I need to detect the changes if data added or removed in class_a or class_b but im only getting change detection if values of objects are string.
Since the keys in my object are dynamic i couldn't iterate the object and create Iterable differs.
Is there anyway to detect changes of array inside the object.

My Implementation:

```
constructor(private differs: KeyValueDiffers) {
      this.keyValueDiffer = differs.find({}).create();
}

ngDoCheck() {
    let changes = this.keyValueDiffer.diff(this.data[this.component.factedBindKey]);
    if (changes) {
        console.log('Changes detected');
    }
}
```

Comment: try to use trackBy

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42108217/how-to-use-trackby-with-ngfor

Comment: I didn't  bind the data in html, I just needed  to pass data in to other function. So i couldn't use ngFor and trackBy.

Comment: ok, when reinit array after do some changes that will fire changeDetection. Examples: [...YOUR_ARRAY] OR Array.from(YOUR_ARRAY) (same possible for objects)

Answer (score 0):

you can test like this

```js
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
}
  
ngOnChanges() {
    let actualData =this.data
    this.mymethod(actualData);
}

and call this line where you want to access that actual data like this

mymethod(data){
this.cd.detach();
//write main logic 
}
```

Comment: If i add this.cd.detach() , then it completely stops detecting any changes .

Comment: try it any other method