# angular mat-checkbox [checked] property is trigger multiple time when the value assigned dynamically

Tags: angular, angular8, angular11, angular12

```
<ul>
<li *ngFor=let choice of checkboxlist.options>

<mat-checkbox [checked]=isChecked(choice) > <mat-checkbox>
<li>
<ul>
```

in ts file I have function for isChecked based on some logic it returns true or false (this works fine) but the functions is get triggering  multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Is the function getting triggered once for each option in your `checkboxlist.options`?

When you update a single selection in your `checkboxlist.options` list, and it is re-rendering the whole DOM for each `<li *ngFor`, you can help it be a little smarter.

For small applications where your looping over a handful of options this is not a big deal.  However, it is good practice and if your list is large then you want to use `trackBy` in your `ngFor`

If you use `trackBy` then your list will ONLY update the list items that are changed.

There's a lot of references out there that will help you build your trackBy method better than I will, here is a good starting point for another [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42108217/how-to-use-trackby-with-ngfor) about it.

Good luck!

Comment: yes the function is getting triggered for each option, even adding the TrackBy did not resolve the issue not sure what is the root cause for it @MindlessRouse

Comment: It's likely because youre looping over an array of native objects `[false, false, true]` instead of an object `[{id:1, value: false},{id:2, value: false},{id:3, value: true}]`.  If you want trackby to do its thing, you would need something like that last one.  All this to say, if it is just a few checkboxes on the page, is there a performance issue with rendering them all on every click?

Comment: What does "choice" and "isChecked" look like?

Comment: @ MindlessRouse
 choice object [ {name: 'ABC', value: false,  actualValue:'1'} ,  {name: 'xyz' value: false,  actualValue:'2'} ]



icChecked(field:string, value:string):boolean{
// Some Logic
return True or False
}