# Angular re-render only changed row in a table with ngrx

Tags: angular, html-table, ngrx

I am using NGRX to load data from remote api, into an array, and after render the array in a classic HTML table. Partially the code looks like this:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.store
      .select(
        createSelector(
          (state: AppState) => state.userProperties,
          (propObject: UserProperties) => propObject
        )
      )
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$))
      .subscribe(({properties, total }) => {
        this.propertyList = properties;
        this.totalFound = total;
      })
```

And render code:

```
      <tbody>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let row of propertyList">
          <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td class="limited">{{ row.id }}</td>
            <td class="limited">{{ categoryLabels[row.category] | _: trans.lang }}</td>
            <td class="limited">{{ contractLabels[row.contract_type] | _: trans.lang }}</td>
            <td class="limited">{{ row.price }}</td>
            <td class="limited">{{ row.city }}</td>
            <td class="limited">
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="table-actions">
                <button (click)="editProperty(row.id)" class="button button-icon">
                  <edit-icon></edit-icon>
                </button>
                <button *ngIf="row.deleted === 0" (click)="archiveProperty(row.id)" title="Delete this property"
                  class="button button-icon">
                  <img src="/assets/images/icons/delete-red.svg" />
                </button>
                <button (click)="toggleExpand(row.id)" class="button button-icon btn-expand">
                  <expand-icon [expanded]="expandedElements[row.id]"></expand-icon>
                </button>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </ng-container>
```

The issue I notice if that if I change a row, example I click setStatus, which changes a row of the array, all the table renders again (causing some flickering).

Is there a way to tell angular to render only the rows of the array which have changed?

Solution (thanks to @Dmytro Demyanenko):
Add trackBy to the ngFor:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let row of propertyList; trackBy: trackByFn">
```

And define trackBy function:

```
  trackByFn(index, row) {
    return JSON.stringify(row);
  }
```

Angular will re-render the ngFor loop element only if the trackBy function returns a different value from the last one returned. In my case some data in the row might change and then I need to re-render.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. You can use **trackBy** for **ngFor**. This is the way to tell angular to render only the rows of the array which have changed.

Please, read more about this here [How to use `trackBy` with `ngFor`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42108217/how-to-use-trackby-with-ngfor)
or here to see an example [Explain ngFor trackBy in Angular](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/explain-ngfor-trackby-in-angular/)

Comment: Didn't know about this TIL, thanks. It worked at best, my trackBy function returns `return JSON.stringify(row);` Angular compares the different values returned by this function to decide if update the row or not.