Angular 14 reactive forms mat radio button group not working as expected
I am using an reactive form in angular Version 14 which has a radio button below is the code provided for the radio button group used
i have a mat radion button group in my form
<div *ngSwitchCase="'radiobutton'">
  <div *ngIf="shouldRenderChildControl(controlName,item,property)">
    <div *ngIf="item.title === 'Contact Number Type'; else otherContent">
      <div *ngFor="let element of item?.data">
        <span *ngIf="CheckIfChildFormControlReq(controlName, item.name)"
          >*</span
        >
        <mat-form-field>
          <label>{{ item.name }}</label>
          <mat-radio-group [formControlName]="item.name">
            <mat-radio-button
              *ngFor="let option of item.data"
              [value]="option.id"
            >
              {{ option.name }}
            </mat-radio-button>
          </mat-radio-group>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </div>
    <ng-template #otherContent> </ng-template>
  </div>
</div>

The above radio button group  isn't responding on select click, and also The UI is getting struck

Also getting "mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl"  error in the console which might be from the radio button group or some other control type

You have the mat-form-field into a *ngFor="let element of item?.data" -but the formControlName is item.name... are you sure? -you can not to have two "inputs" with the same formControlName unless you're using a FormArray.

@Eliseo is mat form field allowed for radio button group ??

::glups!!, I didn't take account about it. I'm afraid than not, but I'm not pretty sure

Try adding a "trackBy" function to your ngFor. Considering all the ngIfs including function calls (which is a bad idea, because Angular has to evaluate the function everytime) might trigger a rerender of the ngFor Loop. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42108217/how-to-use-trackby-with-ngfor
