# ngModel accepts just one character change in Angular 2

Tags: angular, materialize, angular-ngmodel

The picture below shows my table where the data is dynamically set. E.g., it could have 2,3,4 ... columns.

[image]

My html code is below: `<thead>` contains the title values, and `tbody` contains the values that can be modified.

```
<table class="table-conf">
    <thead>
       <tr>
           <th *ngFor="let data of jsonText[0]" style="text-align: center;">{{data}}</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr *ngFor="let data of jsonText; let i=index">
         <ng-container *ngIf="i!=0">
             <td class="padding-table" *ngFor="let dt of data; let j=index">
                 <input style="text-align: center;" [(ngModel)]="jsonText[i][j]">
             </td>
         </ng-container>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Below is an example of `jsonText` variable that I iterated:

```
jsonText Array(6)
     0: (2) ["Task", "Hours per Day"]
     1: (2) ["Work", 11]
     2: (2) ["Eat", 2]
     3: (2) ["Commute", 2]
     4: (2) ["Watch TV", 2]
     5: (2) ["Sleep", 7]
```

The issue is: when I try to modify an element in the table, I can modify just one character at a time. For example: If I want to change `"Eat"` to `"Lunch"`, I need to delete `"Eat"`, then write `L`, click again on the input, write `u`, click again, etc...

Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular2 Dynamic input field lose focus when input changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42322968/angular2-dynamic-input-field-lose-focus-when-input-changes)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As correctly said in other answer, When you bind `jsonText` to `ngModel` then `ngFor` re-evaluate and you lose focus out of input.

and when you do `[(ngModel)]="dt"` then ngModel can't bind to dynamically created variable.
So you face [this issue.](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8602)

So to make it work:

(a) you have to apply `trackBy` function to your `ngFor`, [Read](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4402)

So in HTML add `trackBy` function, and do binding as `[(ngModel)]="data[j]` , Like :

```
 <tr *ngFor="let data of jsonText; let i=index">
         <ng-container *ngIf="i!=0">
             <td class="padding-table" *ngFor="let dt of data; let j=index; trackBy:customTrackBy">
                 <input style="text-align: center;" [(ngModel)]="data[j]">
             </td>
         </ng-container>
</tr>
```

(b) and in your component add the function and track the index.

```
     customTrackBy(index: number, obj: any): any {
         return index;
     }
```

Comment: Thaaaat's it!!! Thank you so much. Your answer solved my problem. Both answers, yours and Everett, helped me understand the situation. Thank you soo much.

Comment: Thanks @anoop , finally found solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your ngFor is binding to jsonText, so every time you edit jsonText[i][j], you're forcing the ngFor directive to re-evaluate, which is why you lose focus.

In this case, just bind directly to 'dt'

```
 <input style="text-align: center;" [(ngModel)]="dt">
```

That way you're editing a field withing jsonText, not the entire object.

In addition, if dt isnt working in the model, then dt probably isnt what you expect it to be.

Add a line to your html template to display dt's value.

```
<tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let data of jsonText; let i=index">
     <ng-container *ngIf="i!=0">
         <td class="padding-table" *ngFor="let dt.value of data; let j=index">
             {{dt.value | json}} // Add this
         </td>
     </ng-container>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Solution**

The issue is with your json data. The jsonText array is just an array of an array of strings or numbers. Not 'objects', so they are not bound to any variable. Thats why ngModel doesn't work on 'dt'. dt isnt given a variable.

So, change how your jsonText array is setup to something like this:

```
jsonText = [
  [{ value: "task", id: 0}, {value: "Hours per day", id: 1}],
  [{ value: "work", id: 2}, {value: "11", id: 3}],
  [{ value: "eat", id: 4}, {value: "commute", id: 5}],
  ....
]
```

[**Working Example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/71kpwhFaHPrSgKwArJao?p=info)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried this on the beginning.But when I do this, I receive the follow message error:

Uncaught Error: Cannot assign to a reference or variable!

Comment: I figured something would error, I'm not exactly sure how your jsonText array is setup. Check my updated answer to help debug.

Comment: I made what you've suggested and the result was what I've shown on the picture and it's the jsonText values: "Work", 1, "Eat", 2, "Commute", 2 ...

Comment: Thank you soo much for the answer. It helped me understand the situation and why it didn't work. Your solution really works but in my case I can't create an object due how the application with "jsonText" works, but your answers with @anoop answer solved my problem. Thank you so much!!

Comment: No problem. I had just remembered trackby. I'd go with that answer too! Cheers.