# Angular 9, issue with inputs using ngFor with object

Tags: angular

Running into an odd issue while creating a simple table of inputs. Pretty new to Angular, hoping it's something simple!

Objective: Create a table of inputs like below.
[image: table of inputs]

**My current code is generating the table above, but when attempting to type any numbers in, it doesn't let you type any more than one number at a time like it's losing focus after every number is entered.**

The code:

1. This is part of the object that I'd like to create the table from

```
FormData = {
grossInputs: {
        "Base Pay": {
            ytd: null,
            lastYear: null,
            yearBeforeLast: null
        },
        Overtime: {
            ytd: null,
            lastYear: null,
            yearBeforeLast: null
        },
        Commissions: {
            ytd: null,
            lastYear: null,
            yearBeforeLast: null
        },
        Bonuses: {
            ytd: null,
            lastYear: null,
            yearBeforeLast: null
        }
    }
}
```

2.
The template

```
What are {{ name }}'s gross earnings?<br>
<table class="table-data">
    <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let headers of grossPayHeaders">
            {{ headers }} <-- "type", "Year to Date", ...
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of formData.grossInputs | keyvalue: originalOrder">
        {{row.key}} 
        <td *ngFor="let col of row.value | keyvalue: originalOrder">
                <input
                    type="number"
                    class="table-cell" 
                    name="{{col.key}}{{row.key}}"
                    [(ngModel)]="formData.grossInputs[row.key][col.key]"
                >
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        Total
        <td *ngFor="let totalof grossTotals" style="text-align: right;">
            {{ total}}
        </td>
    </tr> 
</table>
```

3. This is something I came accross to maintain the order of my keys, because for whatever reason Angular decided to order it by default. So I was having issues with the data-binding not corresponding to where it was in the table

```
originalOrder = (a: KeyValue<number,string>, b: KeyValue<number,string>): number => {
    return 0;
  }
```

Lastly, if I don't use "originalOrder" as the compareFn, and instead use null, it works! Everything functions perfectly! Except I get an error in the console stating that the compareFn must be a function or undefined every time I type something in one of the inputs. Conversely, if I don't use any compareFn, and let it default it does the same thing (only lets you type one number at a time), and of course, nothing is bound properly.

Also, there's a very real possibility that this is just not the right answer. Totally open to anything, thanks for any help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular2 Dynamic input field lose focus when input changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42322968/angular2-dynamic-input-field-lose-focus-when-input-changes)

Comment: Use a trackByFn function

Comment: Yes, both of these are correct! Apparently I'm not any good at google.